# SQL*Loader: Use a field not in the table

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader

Got an odd question, I'm trying to load some data into Oracle using SQL*loader.
The trick is, there is a field provided which I need to use as input to a user function to calculate another field. The original field I don't want to load.

I tried this: however, a FILLER field cannot be referenced as a BIND variable:

```
  LOAD DATA
     APPEND
     INTO TABLE my_table
     (
     XREF_NUM        FILLER   POSITION(8:26),
     ID_NUM                   POSITION(1:1) "my_func(:XREF_NUM)",
     ... other columns ... 
     )
```

Table defintion is just:

```
  ID_NUM
  COL1
  COl2
```

but XREF_NUM does not exist in the table.

How do I set this up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define it as BOUNDFILLER, which means treat it as a "remembered" FILLER.  You can use it in expressions.

```
LOAD DATA
     APPEND
     INTO TABLE my_table
     (
     XREF_NUM   BOUNDFILLER  POSITION(8:26),
     ID_NUM                  POSITION(1:1) "my_func(:XREF_NUM)",
     ... other columns ... 
     )
```

Comment: Very sweet .. didn't know about that.. Works like a charm!  Thank-you!